# How do you calculate the pH range for which one metal precipitates but the other stays in solution?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, solubility, ph, precipitation

The problem I have been asked to solve is:

---

> $\ce{Cd^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^2+}$ (starting concentration $\pu{E-3 mol/L}$) should be separated by precipitation using $\ce{H2S}$. **Does a pH range exist allowing to completely precipitate one metal** (i.e. the remaining concentration of the precipitated ion has to be $\pu{E-5 mol/L}$ or less) **whereas the other stays in solution at its initial concentration?** Please calculate this $\pu{pH}$ range!

> Solubility product: $\ce{(CdS)}$: $\pu{E-27}$; $\ce{(FeS)}$: $\pu{E-19}$; Acid constant $\ce{(H2S)}$: $\pu{E-20}$; concentration of $\ce{H2S}$ = $\pu{0.1M}$.

---

My approach to solving the problem was the following:

$\pu{K_{sp}}$ = [$\ce{M+}$][$\ce{S^2-}$] $\ce{->}$ $\pu{K_{sp}}$ for either metal can be defined in the following way:

$\ce{[S^2-]}$ = $\pu{K_{a}}$ $\frac{[\ce{H2S}]}{[\ce{H+}]}$ $\ce{->}$ the concentration of sulfide ions is given by this expression

[$\ce{M+}$] = $\frac{\pu{K_{sp}}\ce{[H+]}}{\pu{K_{a}[\ce{H2S}]}}$ $\ce{->}$ substituting the second equation into the first we get the concentration of metal ions in terms of $\pu{pH}$.

After this, we must find the $\pu{pH}$ range where the concentration of $\ce{Cd^2+}$ is less than $\pu{E-5 M}$ and the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is greater than $\pu{E-3 M}$.

---

For $\ce{Cd^2+}$:

$\pu{E-5} =\frac{\pu{E-27} \times [\ce{H+}]}{\pu{E-20} \times 0.1}$

Solving for $\ce{H+}$ gives $\ce{H+}$ = $\pu{E-3 M}$, or $\pu{pH = 3}$.

For $\ce{Fe^2+}$:

$\pu{E-3} =\frac{\pu{E-19}\times[\ce{H+}]}{\pu{E-20} \times 0.1}$

Solving for $\ce{H+}$ gives $\ce{H+}$ = $\pu{E-5 M}$, or $\pu{pH = 5}$

**Thus the $\pu{pH}$ range is $\pu{3-5}$**

---

I realise that this is a homework question, but I hope I have shown that I have given this problem some thought. I am really uncertain, whether my approach is correct, especially the step where I found the $\pu{pH}$ at which the concentration of $\ce{Cd^2+}$ ions is less than $\pu{E-5 M}$ (because I could have also calculated the $\pu{pH}$ at which the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ions is less than $\pu{E-5 M}$). Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Gosh, my retina is facing its apocalypse.

Comment: I'll edit the question.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM +1 for your heroic effort!

Comment: Actually I love problems like these as these are the *exact* kinds that come for my competitives.

Comment: @andrej you're right, no worries.

Comment: H2S had two constants. They probably mean  the product of both constants, skipping HS-. So K=Ka1.Ka2=[H+]^2[S^2-]/[H2S] . Be aware of the square.

Comment: @Poutnik - I would have thought, and it is certainly what I was taught, that there were 3 sulfur species too. However the Wikipedia article on hydrogen sulfide says that  $\ce{S^{2-}}$ does not exist in aqueous solution. I'm confused at this point how the sulfide ppt constants would work.

Comment: @MaxW I often read Ka2 is near 13.5-14., so I am not sure  But if it does not exist, all sulfide solubility products are questionable how they are defined.

Comment: @Poutnik - I was looking for the $\ce{K_{a2}}$ when I stumbled on the Wikipedia article. If I remember correctly some of the sulfide ppts are also slow to form. Precipitation also has some sort of kinetic factor since 1 molecule of $\ce{CdS}$ won't precipitate. A particle has to grow to a "large" size to ppt. This question is more interesting than it would seem.

Comment: I'll point out that the question also ignores hydroxide precipitates. The problem statement indicates that there is a $\ce{10^{-8}}$ difference in the sulfide ppts so I'd expect more than a 2 pH unit difference if hydroxide ppts are to be ignored.